# android - How to remove black field on Widget ImageView

Tags: android, android-widget, imageview, android-canvas

Thanks for helping me to solve the problem.
I use  setImageViewBitmap to widget imageview from a  bitmap by drawing round corners with canvas, but it has a black field in imageview's corners. I don't know why this only happens on Widget but didn't happens on my Activity view. 
How to let my corners on Widget look like corners on Activity?

here is my situation

on Widget :
http://goo.gl/YpzhJh

on Activity : 
http://goo.gl/bc09oL

here is my code of making round corners.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        //final int color = 0xff000000;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = 60;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
      }
```

here is the code of setting widget remoteviews

```
 bitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(orgin_bitmap);
 if(bitmap!=null)
     views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.main_imageview, bitmap);
```

here is widget xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_imageview"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/widget_back3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/widget_back2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_redheart"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/widget_back1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/now"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="@color/black"
        android:shadowRadius="3.0"
        android:text="9999"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/trans"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

setbackground(null);
will help

in xml

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it didn't work. It still the same.
thanks~

Comment: post ur code where u put immageview to ur activty please.

Comment: android:background="@null" this should work :D. idk why not... So try this views.setBackgroundResource( 0 ); before setImageViewBitmap

Comment: sorry, I can't find "setBackgroundResuouce" in RemoteViews views